# Function response recall to Ko viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal

My mobile app loads API endpoints at the app login. One of the API endpoints returns data that I can see in the DOM. I need this data loaded into another view/view-model without having to do another API call for the data again.

companyDataService.js - (this returns the api data endpoint that loads on login needed for another view on the app for my view-model)

```
    function getHelpText (companyName, userName, password) {
        return api.helpTextGet(company.name, company.userName, company.password);
    }
```

I want the data returned above to be used for my "help text" view-model so it can be passed to the associated view. Here is what I have attempted in my view-model:

```
    var MyText = ko.observable();

    var company = shell.authenticatedCompany();
    return companyDataService.getHelpText(company.name, company.userName, company.password).then(function (data) {
      if (!data) {
          MyText(document.getElementById('no-help').innerHTML = '<div class="flex-item"><p>Request help from Support:<br /><a href="mailto:support@company.com" class="low-profile-btn btn btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Contact Support</a></p></div>');
      } else {
          MyText(data);
       }
    });



    return {
        MyText: MyText
    };
```

});

Any ideas on how to do this? pre-loaded data to be used in this view-model? If anybody can help with this would be muchly appreciated as Im pulling my hair out looking at promises, q.defer etc... however I think its a lot simpler than that but just can't manage to work it out.

This is my view ko:

```
<section class="help-text">
<div class="flex-container">

    <div id="no-help" class="help-content" data-bind="html: MyText"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your bindings for MyText? Also, what kind of data are you returning from your API? Markup?

Comment: @NickDeFazio Just markup. Added the bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

companyDataService.js - (this returns the api data endpoint that loads on login needed for another view on the app for my view-model)

```
function getHelpText(companyName, userName, password) {
        return api.helpTextGet(company.name, company.userName, company.password).then(function (helpText) {
            company.helpText = helpText;
        });
    }
```

My view model  -

```
      var MyText = ko.observable();

        var company = shell.authenticatedCompany();
        MyText(company.helpText);




    return {
        MyText: MyText
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you have made an API call previously on your page (or another viewmodel) that obtained some data from your server. Now you need that same data in another viewmodel, and do not want to call the API again.

Based on the code posted, I would suggest moving the initial API call out of the viewmodel (as not to repeat it over and over), and instead pass in the value returned once the call has completed.

```
var HelpTextViewModel = function(helpMarkup){
  var self = this;
  var defaultMarkup = '<div class="flex-item"><p>Request help from Support:<br /><a href="mailto:support@company.com" class="low-profile-btn btn btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Contact Support</a></p></div>';

  //Use default text if nothing was passed in
  //Side note - when using the knockout html binding, you can simply call myObservable(myHtml), no need to crawl the dom and set inner html.
  self.helpText = ko.observable((helpMarkup && helpMarkup !== "") ? helpMarkup : defaultMarkup);
};



$.when(myAPICallPromise).done(function(apiData){
  console.log("API data:", apiData);
    ko.applyBindings(new HelpTextViewModel(apiData));
    //Do something else with my API data if I want to...
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mosv0g1g/10/)

In this example, I took what you had, and added a way to pass in an initial value for my observable, and defined a default if nothing is provided, or if it's blank. I also moved the API call out of the view model, so now the view model **only** relies on what was passed in on initialization.

For the API call, I would suggest taking another look at promises and deferreds, but you could accomplish this with a success callback as well. If you are using jQuery for your API calls, [jquery.ajax() implements the promise interface by default](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). In the snippet, I'm assuming a jQuery promise was used for my API call, and when its completed (.done), I initialize my viewmodel with whatever the server gave me back.

In any case, if you do not want to repeat your API calls, move your API call out of your viewmodel, ensure its called only once, and pass the value your API gave you into different parts of your page.